# Reverse engineering Blootooth Low Energy

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, reverse-engineering, wireshark, packet-sniffers

Can someone help me with reverse engineering of a Blootooth low energy device?
I have some data with Wireshark and a sniffer recorded and must now interpret these encrypted data meaningfully.
Furthermore I have to develop an app in which I can visualize the received data. Does anyone know this?

Answer (score 1):

BLE is a published standard, you can determine the data being received by reviewing the standards published here:
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification

Comment: While the BLE spec is published and there are a number of standard services and characteristics I think that the op is trying to determine how a specific peripheral uses its private services and characteristics.

Comment: Agree but you should be able to poll the device using the protocol to get functions available although you may not know what they are or what they mean the device should tell you codes for functions available if it meets the spec.

Comment: Precisely. You can query for he services and characteristics but that doesn't tell you what the values of the characteristics *mean*, which is what the op wants to know.